# sudo apt-get update is not updating repositories in Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, debian, repository, apt

I am trying to update repositories using following command but it is failing:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Here is the output of above command:

```
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://deb.opera.com stable Release.gpg                                                                                        
Hit http://liveusb.info all Release.gpg                                                                                            
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                                                                            
Hit http://deb.opera.com stable Release                                                                                            
Hit http://liveusb.info all Release                                                                                                
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                                                                                 
Hit http://repo.mysql.com wheezy Release.gpg                                                                                       
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com wheezy Release.gpg                                                                                    
Hit http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free i386 Packages                                                                             
Hit http://liveusb.info all/main i386 Packages                                                                                     
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release.gpg                                                                          
Get:1 http://http.debian.net wheezy Release.gpg [1,655 B]                                                                          
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com wheezy Release                                                                                        
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release                                                                              
Hit http://repo.mysql.com wheezy Release                                                                                           
Hit http://linux.dropbox.com wheezy/main i386 Packages                                                                             
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main i386 Packages                                                                   
Get:2 http://http.debian.net wheezy Release [168 kB]                                                                               
Hit http://repo.mysql.com wheezy/mysql-apt-config i386 Packages                                                                    
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main Translation-en                                                                  
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                                                                             
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free Translation-en_US                                                                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                                                                                
Ign http://liveusb.info all/main Translation-en_US                                                                                 
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free Translation-en                                                                            
Ign http://liveusb.info all/main Translation-en                                                                                    
Get:3 http://http.debian.net wheezy/main i386 Packages [5,858 kB]                                                                  
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com wheezy/main Translation-en_US                                                                         
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com wheezy/main Translation-en                                                                            
Get:4 http://http.debian.net wheezy/main Translation-en [3,846 kB]                                                                 
Ign http://repo.mysql.com wheezy/mysql-apt-config Translation-en_US                                                                
Ign http://repo.mysql.com wheezy/mysql-apt-config Translation-en                                                                   
Err http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates Release.gpg                         
Cannot initiate the connection to ftp.tr.debian.org:80 (2001:a98:11::100). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:a98:11::100 80]
Get:5 http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates Release [124 kB]
Err http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/main Translation-en

Err http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/main Translation-en

Get:6 http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/main i386 Packages [3,397 B]
Err http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/main Translation-en

Err http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/main Translation-en

Err http://http.debian.net wheezy-updates/main Translation-en
Cannot initiate the connection to ftp.tr.debian.org:80 (2001:a98:11::100). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:a98:11::100 80]
Fetched 10.0 MB in 1min 5s (152 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to ftp.tr.debian.org:80 (2001:a98:11::100). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:a98:11::100 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Cannot initiate the connection to ftp.tr.debian.org:80 (2001:a98:11::100). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:a98:11::100 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been     Ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Following is my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7 _Wheezy_ - Official Snapshot i386 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20140716-13:13]/ wheezy contrib main contrib non-free non-free

deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main contrib non-free

deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src ftp://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free

## Depôt MultiSystem
deb http://liveusb.info/multisystem/depot all main
# deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy contrib non-free main
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a ipv6 issue. First Method create a file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4` and add this line `Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";` this will force apt to use ipv4. Another secondary method is to add `precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100` to `/etc/gai.conf`